# How to convert object of array of object to array of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have **object of array of object**

```
{
  "94":[{"Full Name":"Phalla Morn"}],
  "95":[{"Full Name":"Pum Chhenghorng"}],
  "99":[{"Full Name":"Proen Pich"}]
}
```

I want to convert it to **array of object**:

```
[
  {"Full Name":"Phalla Morn"}, 
  {"Full Name":"Pum Chhenghorng"},
  {"Full Name":"Proen Pich"}
]
```

Please help.

Comment: What code have you tried? Can you show that so we can help?

Comment: Have you tried doing anything on this? The solution can't be any simpler.

Comment: I have tried many other things because I don't know how to use ``[].concat(...Object.values(arr))``. This one works for me. thank.s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the internal arrays with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and flatten by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const arr = {"94":[{"Full Name":"Phalla Morn"}],"95":[{"Full Name":"Pum Chhenghorng"}],"99":[{"Full Name":"Proen Pich"}]};
    
const result = [].concat(...Object.values(arr));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Except .values is not supported by IE

Comment: We live in the world of Babel and polyfills, and most importantly projects that don't need to support IE.

Comment: Lucky you. No IE support. Anyway, I found this more elegant: `var arr = Object.values(obj).map(o => o[0]);` Still voted up

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.values` to extract the values from an object, and then use `[].concat(...` to flatmap:

```js
const input = {
  "94": [{
    "Full Name": "Phalla Morn"
  }],
  "95": [{
    "Full Name": "Pum Chhenghorng"
  }, {
    "Full Name": "example other"
  }],
  "99": [{
    "Full Name": "Proen Pich"
  }]
};
const output = [].concat(...Object.values(input));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Not supported by IE

Comment: Nor is `const` nor `map` nor many other features, but that's what Babel and polyfills are for - best to write clear, concise code and transpile it later.

Comment: const, let map etc is supported by IE11

Comment: Oh, huh, TIL, thanks. Somehow I had gotten it into my head that 2013-IE11 didn't support any of the ES2015 features

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```js
var obj = {
    "94":[{"Full Name":"Phalla Morn"}],
    "95":[{"Full Name":"Pum Chhenghorng"}],
    "99":[{"Full Name":"Proen Pich"}]
    }

var arr = Object.values(obj).map(o => o[0]);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Very elegant. No IE support without a shim

Comment: @mplungjan May be OP is working on server side and browser is not an issue. :)

Comment: true. We should ask

Comment: This won't work if there is more than one object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `forEach` loops and make sure that if there are multiple objects in array `94` or `95` then that is also taken into account by this dynamic code logic:

```js
let obj = {
  "94":[{"Full Name":"Phalla Morn"}],
  "95":[{"Full Name":"Pum Chhenghorng"}],
  "99":[{"Full Name":"Proen Pich"}]
}; 
let res = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{
   obj[key].forEach((innerObj)=>{
     res.push(innerObj);
   }); 
});
console.log(res);
```

Or you can use `Object.values` together with the `spread` operator:

```js
let obj = {
  "94":[{"Full Name":"Phalla Morn"}],
  "95":[{"Full Name":"Pum Chhenghorng"}],
  "99":[{"Full Name":"Proen Pich"}]
}; 
let res = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{
    res.push(...Object.values(obj[key]));
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: .values is not supported by IE

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS -  since Object.values is not supported by IE at all

```js
var arr = [],
    obj =  {"94":[{"Full Name":"Phalla Morn"}],"95":[{"Full Name":"Pum Chhenghorng"}],"99":[{"Full Name":"Proen Pich"}]};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
  arr.push(obj[k][0])
});
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: What if `obj[k]` has more that one object inside it? We can make the code run dynamically to handle that case too.

Comment: Sure. but not part of the spec

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it should take care of arrays with multiple objects in its value.

```js
let data = {
      "94": [{
        "Full Name": "Phalla Morn"
      }],
      "95": [{
        "Full Name": "Pum Chhenghorng"
      },{
        "Full Name": "Ryann"
      }],
      "99": [{
        "Full Name": "Proen Pich"
      }]
    };
    
    let obj = [];
    
    Object.keys(data).map(item => {
      data[item].map(item => {
        obj.push(item);
      });
    });
    
    console.log(obj);
```